# "this" gets resetted C++

Tags: c++, class

I am trying to make a class like string(for learning purposes) and i have the following
files

var.cpp:

```
#include "var.hpp"


var::var(){}

var::var(const char* v) {
    (*this) = v;
}

var var::operator=(const char*& v) {
    if(string_var) {
        free((void*)string_var);
        string_var = NULL;
    }
    if(!v) return (*this);

    string_var = strdup(v);
    return (*this);
}

var::~var() {
    if(string_var && *string_var) free((void*)string_var);
}
```

var.hpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdlib>


class var {
private:
    const char* string_var = NULL;
public:
    var();
    var(const char* v);
    var operator=(const char*&);
    ~var();
};
```

test.cpp:

```
#include "var.hpp"

int main() {
    var v1 = "test";
}
```

it compiles without any errors.

with gdb i ran the compiled program and i found that when it goes from the constructor to the `operator=`, the `operator=` does its job correctly but when it returns i check the `this`(like: `p *this`) and the `string_var` is `""`.

I am still learning so please help me understand why and how to fix it.

***EDIT***

After some debugging i found that the destructor gets called ***inside*** the constructor; at least that's what i understand from the following output:

```
Breakpoint 1, var::~var (this=0x7fffffffde60, __in_chrg=<optimized out>) at var.cpp:21
21  var::~var() {
(gdb) back
#0  var::~var (this=0x7fffffffde60, __in_chrg=<optimized out>) at var.cpp:21
#1  0x00005555555552ef in var::var (this=0x7fffffffde80, v=0x555555556005 "ok") at var.cpp:7
#2  0x00005555555551f7 in main () at test.cpp:5
```

Comment: Minor point: you don't need those parentheses around `*this`. In all the places where it's used, `*` binds more tightly than the rest of the expression, so the parentheses are redundant.

Comment: @PeteBecker i know that, it just helps me read the code a bit easier. thanks though

Comment: Self-assignment will cause some problems  The assignment operator should guard against that, preferably by doing the steps in such a way that the heavy lifting happens first, and then changing the state of the object happens second, which will also help if an exception is thrown during the heavy lifting.

Comment: var::var(const char* v) {
    (*this) = v;
} this makes my head spin. I am not sure what the compiler will do with it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you are missing proper copy/move constructors and you are returning `*this` by value.

Your compiler makes a copy constructor for you which makes shallow copies and messes up your `free`s (you end up killing things that have already been killed).

Change the return type of your assignment operator to `var&` to return a reference and avoid a copy. Although that will fix your code, you are strongly advised to write your own copy/move constructors/assignment operators.

I would also advise you leave C behind and embrace the `new`/`delete` operators.

Finally, your use of the assignment operator here is misguided. First, the pointer reference type is superfluous. Second, you could move the logic of that operator to the constructor and you could still define `v1` like you did in `main` without overloading `=`. You should instead overload it so that it accepts a const reference to type `var` to make a copy (ideally another overload to rvalue reference for move semantics).

Comment: thanks, that's a explanation. The part of new/delete, i know but as i said it's for learning purposes, i am trying to learn a bit of memory management and i want to sometime learn C, so i think malloc/free is better than new/delete(for later going deeper to C)

Comment: @user898238409 note that `strdup` isn't a part of C until a future (supposedly) standard, it's a POSIX function otherwise - and some platform lack it or have `_strdup`

Answer (score 1):

Rule of 3\5 not followed so returning `var` from `operator=` in constructor results in shallow copy of `var`, The temporal object then gets deleted and it frees memory.

You have to

a) have implement copy constructor;

b) Fix that destructor, because it leaks memory if string is empty (but there is still memory allocated);

c) consider avoiding use of strdup and free and use new\delete and memcpy.